# Android EditText error not going away when moved to MapFragment tab in ViewPager

Tags: android

There is a `ViewPager` with 4 fragments.

1: `MapFragment`

2,3: `RecyclerView` (Read only pages)

4: `FormFragment`

The input form has input `EditText` fields which shows a field required error when it's empty. I'm resetting the error in `onPause()` of `FormFragment`. When the user moves to the `RecyclerView` fragments, the error is going away but when we move to the `MapFragment`, the error is not going away. It's coming on the side of the map. I've tried `mMapView.getMapAsync()` in `onResume()` and no success

Form with error

[image]

Moved from form to map

[image]

`recyclerview` when moved from either the map or form vanishes the error

[image]